# Why does jQuerys' show function work in this way?

Tags: jquery, css, html, show

i am just showing thank message on button click.

### [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6w2nq99/)

In this demo Thank you message comes from `left side`.

```html
<div class='btn'></div>
<div class="thank-you">Thank You</div>
```

```css
.btn {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: green;
    display:block;
}
.thank-you {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.thank-you').show('slow');
});
```

My problem :

1. why it is come from left side? (actually it should only show me element like `fadeIn`)
2. How to show thank you message from top side using show function if possible. (`Without animation function`)

**update** - Is it possible using time and height property or other way to show thank message from top (looks animated).

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy my bad. I copied from a fiddle which I had edited. Fixed.

Comment: @Prashant, you're rejecting all answers that advise you to use `fadeIn()`, but I'm afraid that's the only solution. Plain `show()` animates both the opacity of the element and its width, which results in the sliding effect you want to get rid of. I'm don't know of any way to change `show()`'s behavior regarding this, so using `fadeIn()` instead does look like the only alternative.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yup, I know that, but I believe the questioner does want `show()` to perform an animation. Removing the animation does fix the problem, but probably not in a satisfying way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1: Why does it animate like that?**

The reason it animates is because you specified `slow` and the text is *centered*. As the width animates it appears to slide in.

Using `slow` implies you *want* animation, so it animates everything it feels it should to meet your aim (width, height, margins etc).

For example this will just show it http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6w2nq99/16/:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').show();
});
```

My personal preference is to `fadeIn`. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6w2nq99/28/

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').fadeIn();
});
```

**Question 2 (updated): How to animate down from the top**

As for your second question, the position is purely down to your styling. You can place it anywhere.

Try animating the top position (of an absolutely position element): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6w2nq99/30/

```
$('.thank-you').hide();
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').show().animate({'top': 0});
});
```

*Note: the initial styling of the thank you is offscreen (negative top position).*

Comment: @Prashant: Added new version that I think will meet your requirements.

Comment: @TrueBlueAusssie : thanks. but i think 2nd question is not possible as per your answer and statement.

Comment: @Prashant: I do not understand what you wanted different for the second part. If you can clarify your aim, I will try to show a better example.

Comment: your solution is correct. But i am just asking, is it possible to move from top to bottom using `show()` function. as happened in my 1st question (left to right).

Comment: Not easily without the width still animating as well: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d6w2nq99/32/

Answer (score 1):

1. From JQuery documentation:

> When a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided, .show() becomes an animation method. The .show() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously.
>   [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

It is animated in the way you see it (from left to right) as this function was created in such way in JQuery core.

2. You cannot "show from top side", you can show any object in the place it is, or use the default left->right animation. If you want to slide it from top you can use functions like slideDown().

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.slideDown()` then,

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').slideDown('slow');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6w2nq99/2/)

Comment: Sorry this is not my answer. Read questions again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: none` from `.thank-you`(CSS) and change your jQuery to:

```
$('.thank-you').hide();
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/d6w2nq99/14/)

Answer (score -2):

Check here:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.thank-you').show("slide");
});
```

Comment: use callback function to change the position.

Comment: Try explaining why your answer works and how it is different from what the original poster has in the question. An answer like this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

if you want the element to slide from top then you'd have to use animation properties

[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/d6w2nq99/25/)

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
$('.thank-you').animate({ 
    top: "300px",
  }, 500 );
});
```

Comment: If you reread the question you will find words "Without animation function".

Comment: You do know that this is the only way to achieve something of that sorts right? ;)

Comment: So does OP. He was asking for OTHER solutuin if possible.